# NO cmd_vel on rqt graph

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to navigate P3AT robot spawned in usarsim through teleop_twist_keyboard package (in ROS).

I have connected ros to usarsim using *executive_usarsim package* and spawned the P3AT robot in usarsim, but when i run teleop_twist_keyboard and presses keys to move the robot, nothing happens. please help me out.

I have tried to  run **$rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph**, the following rqt graph appears: [Click to view rqt_graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/35r80a3nllzub8e/Screenshot%20from%202014-09-24%2022%3A19%3A25.png?dl=0)

then i have run **$ rostopic echo /executive_usarsim/status**, following graph appeared: [Click to view graph](https://tucrlab.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/executive.png)

**then i observed** the **cmd_vel is not present**. what to do next. please help.

**NOTE**: i am using ROS-fuerte on UBUNTU 12.04 LTS. [with USARSim simulator]
**see full description**: [click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8ke6fw890cws5i/executive%20_usarsim_issue.docx?dl=0)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193559/no-cmd_vel-on-rqt-graph/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2014-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-27**:
cmd_vel is not published so its not on rqt_graph. try `rostopic info cmd_vel` to see topic publishers and subcribers

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-10**:
hello, @bvbdort . from rostopic info cmd_vel.

```
publisher: teleop_twist_keyboard

subscriber: None
```

since no one is subscriber.
i want executive_usarsim to be a subscriber.

here is the rqt graph obtained.
https://tucrlab.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/executive.png

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2014-10-17**:
Are you sure that executive_usarsim is subscribing to cmd_vel topic? You may wanna view "All Nodes and Topics" in rqt_graph (Upper left drop down menu) or check it using `rostopic list`. Also, check your launch file if you are using `remap` to change topic names.

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-23**:
i am using usarsim_inf & it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi @sumant,

you executive_usarsim node is not subscribing to the `/cmd_vel` topic that's why it is not shown in you rqt_graph.
you can do following things to drive robot:-

1. Check, on which topic your executive_usarsim node is expected to receive twist message and remap the teleop_twist_keyboard from `/cmd_vel` to the identified topic.
2. Use usarsim_inf insted of executive_usarsim.

---

Originally posted by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) with karma: 351 on 2015-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1